# how to use @ symbol at binary concat?

Tags: elixir

My code of using @symbol in the binary concat is as follows, and tried 2 times, but still have the same problem.

```
defmodule Mechanics.Servo do

 @const_command_request_prefix  <<0x12,0x4c>> # <---- this symbol cause the problem

 @const_command_response_prefix <<0x05,0x1c>> 
  defp rotate!(servoPid,servoId,angle,arrive_angle,power) do
    # command = <<@const_command_request_prefix::binary-size(2), servoId::16, arrive_angle::16, power::16 >>
  end
end
```

error message:

```
[{
    "resource": "/Users/yuchen/Documents/Project/CY2/mechanics/lib/mechanics/mechanics_servo.ex",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "(CompileError) literal string in bitstring supports only endianness and type specifiers, which must be one of: little, big, native, utf8, utf16, utf32, bits, bytes, binary or bitstring\n\nStacktrace:\n  │ (elixir 1.13.4) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:164: :elixir_bitstring.expand_specs/7\n  │ (elixir 1.13.4) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:38: :elixir_bitstring.expand/8\n  │ (elixir 1.13.4) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:26: :elixir_bitstring.expand/5",
    "source": "Elixir",
    "startLineNumber": 114,
    "startColumn": 5,
    "endLineNumber": 114,
    "endColumn": 109
}]
```

I changed it as follows, still have the same problem

```
  defp rotate!(servoPid,servoId,angle,arrive_angle,power) do
    # command = <<@const_command_request_prefix::16, servoId::16, arrive_angle::16, power::16 >>

  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concatenating existing binaries, use `::binary`:

```elixir
iex(1)> prefix = <<0x12, 0x4c>>
<<18, 76>>
iex(2)> <<prefix::binary, 123>>
<<18, 76, 123>>
```

This works fine using module attributes too:

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  @bar <<1, 2>>

  def test do
    <<@bar::binary, 3>>
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
iex> Example.test
<<1, 2, 3>>
```

Comment: I want to use a constant binary prefix, otherwise the same binary prefix will appear many times in the source code. So @ symbol is used for const value and the problem appears. Your solution doesn't use constant, not suitable for my problem.

Comment: It works fine with module attributes too. The error is not related to @, it is because you cannot use `::16` with a binary.

Comment: @ChenYu I have added an example using @